# Styling ajaxFileUpload to not expend when displaying file types

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax-upload

I use the AjaxFileUpload control in my applilcation, but each time I choose file (or drag) the control expend its width beacuse it has to show the file type information.

I tired to assign it with a css class and setting the width, but it still changes.

**this is the pic before and after I choose a file:**
[image: **this is the pic before and after I choose a file:**]

**this is my aspx part:**

```
 <tr>
            <td style = "text-align:right;">

                <asp:AjaxFileUpload ID="AjaxFileUpload1" OnUploadComplete="AjaxFileUpload1_UploadComplete" runat="server" ThrobberID="myThrobber" MaximumNumberOfFiles="1" AllowedFileTypes="pdf,doc,docx,ppt,pptx,xls,xlsx,jpg,jpeg" CssClass="uploader"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
```

**the class:**

```
.uploader
{
    width:300px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What if you put the uploader in a Div with that width set?  Can you force it with the parent?